# Equivalent of ScriptsToProcess after module load in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

When a module is imported using Import-Module I would like that module to dot source a set of scripts (if they exist) in the context of whatever executes Import-Module (the callee) - not in the context of the module.  It's not clear how to do this.

There is a "ScriptsToProcess" part of the module manifest which contains scripts to run *before* loading the module in the callee scope however there does not seem to be an equivalent for after the module has been loaded.  Is there a straightforward way to achieve this behaviour?

Here is an example from a psm1 file which does not work because it is dot sourcing in to the scope of the module rather than dot sourcing in to the scope of the callee (typically where you do Import-Module).

```
# Define plugin location
$PluginLocation = Join-Path (Split-Path $profile) PluginScripts

if ($PSIse) {
# If plugin location does not exist tell the user.
if (-not (Test-Path $PluginLocation) )  {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "There is no plugin directory $PluginLocation if you wish to automatically load plugin scripts please create this directory and place the scripts there."
} else {
    Write-Host "Looking for scripts in $PluginLocation"
    Get-ChildItem $PluginLocation -Recurse -Filter *.ps1 | % { 
        Write-Host "Sourcing $($_.Name)"
        . $_.FullName 
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Can't you put it in your .psm1 file? Personally I have an InitializeModule function which is called immediately after functions / cmdlets / etc have been loaded (and is therefore the last line of the .psm1 file).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me.  I've updated my question to include an example of what is not working.  The code is at the end of the psm1 file.  Note that it does run and do the dot sourcing.  I'm sure this is a "scope" question.